# Elasticsearch not returning result for single word query

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I have a basic Elasticsearch index that consists of a variety of help articles. Users can search for them in my Python/Django app.

The index has the following mappings:

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "body": {
                "type": "text"
            },
            "category": {
                "type": "nested",
                "properties": {
                    "category_id": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "category_title": {
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "ignore_above": 256,
                                "type": "keyword"
                            }
                        },
                        "type": "text"
                    }
                }
            },
            "title": {
                "type": "keyword"
            },
            "date_updated": {
                "type": "date"
            },
            "position": {
                "type": "integer"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I basically want the user to be able to search for a query and get any results that match the article title or category.

Say I have an article called "I Can't Remember My Password" in the "Your Account" category.

If I search for the article title exactly, I see the result. If I search for the category title exactly, I also see the result.

But if I search for just "password", I get nothing. What do I need to change in my setup/query to make it so that this query (or similarly non-exact queries) also returns the result?

My query looks like:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [{
                    "multi_match": {
                        "fields": ["title"],
                        "query": "password"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "nested": {
                        "path": "category",
                        "query": {
                            "multi_match": {
                                "fields": ["category.category_title"],
                                "query": "password"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I have read other questions and experimented with various settings but no luck so far. I am not doing anything particularly special at index time in terms of preparing the fields so I don't know if that's something to look at. I'm just using the `elasticsearch-dsl` defaults.

Comment: Is data being returned for more than one word query?

Comment: Yes. As I said above, if I search for "Your Account" or "I Can't Remember My Password", I see the article returned. Just not if I search for "password".

Comment: And if you type "Password", keyword is case sensitive.

Comment: Still no results regardless of query case.

Comment: Ok this is an index, issue you index "I Can't Remember My Password" as a keyword right? so you can only search this using exact match. Re-Index it as text and it should be ok.

Comment: That did it, thanks. If you post it as an answer I'll accept it. Elasticsearch documentation is so dense that even figuring out something as trivial as this is hard work, especially if you're getting started!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to reindex the title field as text rather than keyword. The latter only allows exact matching.

Credit to [LeBigCat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58612191/elasticsearch-not-returning-result-for-single-word-query#comment103536516_58612191) for pointing that out in the comments. They haven't posted it as an answer so I'm doing it on their behalf to improve visibility.